# IE's security alert removal

Tags: security, ssl

I have a site that can be accessed both through http (http://mysite.com) and https (https://mysite.com). The https version holds secured content, while the http content is for public use. Both contents are on the same server.

Some of the https pages contain some elements such as images that are hosted on the http pages. So when one goes to the https site, IE's security alert pops up saying that the content required contains nonsecure data. knowing that there is no risk anyway, I want to stop that popup. Is this something to be done only through the IE's settings on the client side or do I need to do something about the SSL certificate and configurations? Any guide is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have a genuine security problem that breaks the protection of SSL and could lead to your users unknowingly leaking their own data to an attacker. Attempting to hide this problem from your users is arguably a malicious act in its own right. *Fix* your problem; don't attempt to mask it from your innocent users.

Comment: Sure Cheekysoft. I am actually working on this and at quick pace:) Thanks again for all your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE isn't the only browser that will give a popup of that nature. From memory, Firefox and Chrome have similar warnings (like they remove the padlock, or make the `https` go red in the address bar, instead of green).

The only way you can get it to go away is to only reference https resources in https pages. Have you checked to see what you're referring to doesn't have a secure version? All of the tools I have used generally have an equivalent `https://` domain.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually on Firefox and Chrome there was no alert; it is just on IE that I get security alerts and that non-secured data are not displayed. Well, after putting a copy of those images on the secured side and linking to those, at least images appeared on IE as well, but I still get the alert. I know there are some other elements left that I haven't been able to find them, that's why the alert, but I was wondering if there was a way on the server side to tell browsers to ignore any elements hosted on the http side of my side and let them through.

Comment: Firefox/Chrome aren't as intrusive by design - but I'm confident if you look around, view page info, those warnings are there. My best recommendation to fix this would be to install Firebug for Firefox, or just use Chrome and right click > inspect element. From here, you will see a "Network" tab. Click it, and refresh the page. You'll see the server access every resource it needs to load your page - just look at any that aren't secure and change them. Unfortunately there is no setting ignoring warnings, since it essentially says 'please be insecure for a bit'. Browsers won't do that happily.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay Shah for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Please understand that the alert is there for a reason. The SSL certificate in place protects against [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack)*. If you load in resources from non-https sources, then the man-in-the-middle protection you otherwise would have, is lost. The user's data may still be encrypted, but it doesn't really matter if the user is sending all his data to an attacker's computer that is decrypting it itself!

You need to remember that HTTPS is an all-or-nothing scheme. **As soon as you introduce a non-HTTPS element into your page, you have essentially lost all the security that SSL has to provide.**

Please mount your resources (or somehow make them available) on both HTTP and HTTPS URLs and load them accordingly. If you don't you are putting your users at unnecessary risk.

*only if you have a fully valid SSL certificate.

Comment: Whether to report a warning/error for this is something that is under current discussion in the browser developer community- so expect this to change. Everyone thinks that ideally browsers should refuse to load such pages at all, however the only reason that they don't all even as much as warn/error at the moment, is that there are so many ill-configured HTTPS sites out there right now, that it would piss off the users too much if it was introduced. Please don't add another ill-configured site to the list